# Make specific color an emission

Tags: node-editor, shaders, emission, shader-nodes

I am trying to make the blue color on my model an emission so that it creates light and looks like it was just fired.

Here is the model:
[image]

Here is the node setup:
[image]

Comment: This seems rather easy from the node setup, though I’m not sure how the node setup given produces that result. But anyway…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first color ramp (with the blue in it), change the **alpha** for the non-blue stops to zero. Then, pipe the output color into Emission Color, and the output alpha into Emission Strength.

Edit: Like this.
[image: my node setup]

Comment: Well, that's cool and all...but I want there to still be white and black too. Unless I'm still not getting it right?

Comment: If you’re node set up is the material that is hooked to that brick and there’s not some really strange thing I don’t know about, what I did should leave white and black not glowing because alpha would be controlling the emission strength and turning it off when the part wasn’t blue.

Comment: Would you show me a picture of your node setup?

Comment: @MicahVera Ok, let me materialize it…

Comment: @MicahVera done. Sorry the pipes are so tight there, should’ve spread them out . Color and Alpha are respectively connected to Emission and Emission Strength.

Comment: @MicahVera The Alpha setting in the color has absolutely no effect when you plug it in the _Base Color_ input, because it only uses RGB values, no matter how transparent you've set the color. So Zargul's setup works just fine. And you can multiply the Alpha value to get stronger emission, just like vklidu suggested in his answer (which is basically the same like this, only the Alpha is switched which makes an Invert node necessary).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ha :) Right ... my fault. How could I skip such obvious thing?

Comment: @vklidu happens to me all the time when I'm trying to figure something out :D

Comment: Great! Guys! Thanks!